# How do i delegate domain admin to cross forest account

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2019

I currently have a setup involving two domains. In Domain 1, there is a Domain Controller (DC) and a Gateway (GW) configured for Windows Admin Center. A two-way forest-wide trust has been established between these two domains. My objective is to manage the Active Directory (AD) of Domain 2 using my account from Domain 1 within Windows Admin Center.

To achieve this, I have attempted to add myself to the "builtin\administrators" group in Domain 2, but unfortunately, I am unable to access the AD from the Admin Center. Surprisingly, when I use a Domain 2 admin account to log in from the Admin Center, it works perfectly. Additionally, I tried granting myself the "Enterprise Admin" role, but that did not yield the desired results either.

I'm encountering an issue where I cannot add my Domain 1 account to the Domain 2 "domain admins" group because Domain 1 does not appear in the available locations when I attempt to perform this action. Can anyone provide insight into the specific rights or permissions that I may be missing to resolve this situation?

Your assistance and expertise would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `I'm encountering an issue where I cannot add my Domain 1 account to the Domain 2 "domain admins" group because Domain 1 does not appear in the available locations when I attempt to perform this action. Can anyone provide insight` Domain Admins is a Global Group. Global Groups may only have members from the current domain.

Comment: Yeah this limitation is unfortunate, we have solved this by creating a dedicated admin user in the trusted domain

Comment: Is there any alternative method for incorporating an account from a different domain into domain admins, or granting the necessary permissions to manage and access Active Directory?

Answer (score 0):

Domain Admins is a "global" type group that doesn't allow to have foreign members. It's by designed.